# Como ler um float com Scanner

Tags: java, float, scanner

O meu problema é o seguinte:

```
package com.vreawillsaveyou01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        float number = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Quando digito um número com ponto flutuante, usando o ponto como separador decimal (por exemplo, `3.92`), o programa dá o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
at com.vreawillsaveyou01.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

O que estou a fazer de errado e como posso corrigir?

Comment: o código parece correto, está digitando o número com ponto ou vírgula?

Comment: estou digitando com ponto

Comment: @RicardoPontual por exemplo quando ponho 3.92 dá-me aquele erro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O formato de um `float` reconhecido pelo `Scanner` (incluindo o separador decimal) depende do [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) que ele está usando.

Se você não especifica nenhum *locale*, é usado o *default* que está configurado na JVM (que você pode consultar qual é chamando o método [`Locale.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault())).

Na minha máquina, por exemplo, o *default* é `pt_BR` (português do Brasil), e o separador decimal é a vírgula (então este código só funciona se eu digitar, por exemplo, `3,92`).

---

No caso, para o formato que usa o ponto como separador decimal, basta usar um *locale* que use esta configuração. Uma opção é a [constante predefinida para o inglês americano](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#US):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US); // setar o locale
float number = scanner.nextFloat();
System.out.println(number);
```

Com isso, você pode digitar `3.92` que o número será lido corretamente (mas agora `3,92` não funciona mais).